# Best Practice GCP - GKE | Multiple services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have different GCP projects namely for DEV/STAGE/PROD. 
In DEV project we do have **two services** running in one cluster as part of Phase 1, in custom VPC network and subnet.

As the project is expanding which is called as Phase 2, we would adding more services to the DEV GCP project where the services would go from 2 services to 6.

The discussion currently we are having was that for phase 2, whether to have the services in :
- same cluster Or 
- different cluster

Considering the ingress rules, and page routing policies, it would be great if veterans can give some leads , which of the above approach would be good for the project?

Comment: I was able to find a link that might be useful in describing the [GKE best practice](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-best-practices-season-one-11119aee1d10). Keep in mind that capacity is key in the choice you make

Comment: Define what resources two services use. Defined how you configured GKE. For a small GKE cluster with one master and three nodes, two services or six or twenty won't make much difference. It just depends on the resources required by each service/pod/container in CPU, memory and network bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and pointers, i shall post my updates here @Adebisi

Comment: @JohnHanley I have GKE cluster with 3 nodes and n1-standard-8 type machines. Since some of the applications are in JAVA spring boot and some on Node JS, i presume they need much more resources

Comment: I can write a Java App that only needs 100mils or 2000. There is not enough details. n1-standard-8 is a good selection for a small cluster. Unless your apps are heavy resource consumers, I would run them and benchmark behavior.

Comment: Your question about DEV/STAGE/PROD. I always run each one in different clusters. Development, Staging and Production should not be mixed. Dev and Staging sometimes, but never with Production.

Comment: @JohnHanley One questions i had is that these six services can be in separate namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same cluster. If you have insufficient resources to deploy all the pods you need for the various services, consider scaling up the cluster instead of creating a new one. You may also want to consider [node pool autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) or [node auto provisionning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning).

There are really only 2 limitations on the number of services in a cluster: the total number of k8s objects (this is somewhere near 300k~400k and is a limitation of etcd), and the number of service IPs provided at cluster creation (the secondary range you assigned for services).

Aside from the above two limitations, I don't really see much of a reason to create new clusters for the new services. If you have in house design requirements, that is different, but fomr a purely k8s or GKE point of view, you can definitely continue to use the same cluster.

Comment: This is a great pointer, we have concluded to reduce the number of clusters and use  namespaces instead.